# Print pointervalue

Tags: c

I have
char* data; 
which has a buffer dumped into it. I want to view the content of this char*. I do not know the size of this pointer data so How do I print it?! Thank you

Comment: 1) You should add the 'homework' tag. 2) Show your code, including variable declarations, how the `char*` was declared and initialized. 3) Show what you've tried so far that doesn't work, explain what you expected it to do and why it didn't do as you expected. 4) Listen to @Luzhin and accept some answers. If you don't want to participate in the community by respecting the way it works, perhaps you should look for help somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: I checked the link you suggested, but I do not see any accept buttons on my screen?!

Comment: Look at the answers to your questions. In the upper left corner, you'll see a vote count. Directly below that, you'll see the outline of a checkmark - clicking that checkmark marks the question as accepted (it will be filled in with green). You can also vote on posts by clicking on the arrows above and below the vote count (above being an upvote and below being a downvote).

Comment: @Ken I have accepted the answers too. Thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `char*` is `NUL`-terminated, use `printf("%s\n",data);`.

If the data are not `NUL`-terminated, this may cause a segmentation fault.

If your data have some format other than ASCII characters, you're going to need to write some code to print it.

Comment: Please don't answer non-questions, especially ones from people who look like they're trying to get homework answers. It prevents them from learning how to ask questions, how to actually put some effort into figuring things out on their own, and means that people who actually **do** learn end up maintaining the messes they make later on. Answering questions like this is nothing but trying to gain rep at the expense of preventing their education.

Comment: @Ken Hi I am a beginner with C. Sorry I was not clear with my questions. And I was not trying to complete a homework I am learning the language online bymyself and I am trying few code at home to understand it better. Thank you for your concern...I will remember to ask only valuable questions. Also I am unable to see any accept buttons on my screen as shown in the link can you please help me with that. I will be more than happy to work with standards. Thank you for your time

Comment: @kiran: It's not that you didn't post a "valuable" question; it's that you didn't post a complete or answerable question. You didn't provide enough information to allow someone to answer, or to show you'd actually tried to figure it out yourself first. If you're not willing to put any effort into it, why should you expect others to do so?

Comment: @Ken Sorry for not providing the required information. I always do try the code. even in this case, I was not very familiar with sprintf and printf. So i searched online for printng the char* Initially I tried with printf but i was trying to print the char* as an array &a[1] which later I understood to make no sense. That is y i thought of asking your boards help with pointers and printing. Please do not mistake me....I will provide all my previous works before asking a question. Thank you for your feedback.